# Linking python variables to a HTML script

Tags: python, html

I've written a Python 3.2 script to select 10 random questions out of a list of 18, having extracted them from a SQLite 3 database. The script works fine, but I now want to render this using HTML - I know how to make question boxes in HTML, but not how to get the asked question to print, in the place of a "question 1" placeholder.

HTML code below:

```
def PrintGame():
    print( """
    <html>
    <div id = "textbody">
            <h2>Quiz</h2>
                <form method="post" action="quiz.cgi">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 1:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A1"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 2:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A2"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 3:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A3"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 4:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A4"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 5:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A5"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 6:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A6"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 7:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A7"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 8:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A8"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 9:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A9"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <td>Question 10:</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A10"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit Answers"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
             </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    """)
```

Just to clarify, I want to replace the "Question n"-type things with the questions pulled from the SQLite 3 database. The questions are loaded into QASKEDN variables (where N is replaced by the question number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just want string formatting, but with a flexible format string/variable.

I haven't checked, but something like this perhaps?

```
def PrintGame():
    htmlquestions = []
    for question in QASKEDN:
        htmlquestions.append("""
                        <tr>
                              <td>{} :</td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="A1"/></td>
                        </tr>""".format(question))
    html = ("""
    <html>
    <div id = "textbody">
            <h2>Quiz</h2>
                <form method="post" action="quiz.cgi">
                    <table border="0">""" 
    + "".join(htmlquestions) + 
    """                </table>
                </form>
             </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    """)
```

*Update:* now with opening triple double quote for the last lines.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't look like it'll work - it messes up formatting of other things, turning them into strings, and I can't see why that is

Comment: What other things? In the end, all your HTML will be one big string, so everything will be turned into strings.

Comment: It turns the subroutine below it into string format for some reason (the subroutine that deals with the form)

Comment: In which case, there is likely a still open string because of a missing double quote (which then, surprisingly, doesn't cause an error). In fact, if you copy-pasted my code, you'll find there's no opening triple double quote after the last `plus`. I have updated the code so that that's correct. (I did say I hadn't checked it; I'm surprised your text editor or Python didn't catch it.)

Comment: I had copy-pasted it, wasn't sure what was wrong though. Will the N in QASKEDN be replaced by the number? (the numbers 1-10 are needed)

Comment: If you have to ask that, you're better off studying the Python tutorial a bit more. But `QASKEDN` is a `list`, each list item being the string containing the question. E.g., `["What is your favourite colour?", "What is the capital of Assyria?"]`.

Comment: That was me being thick, rather than me not knowing enough Python, derp. I'll try it, see what I get back.

Comment: Doesn't work. Running the subroutine in Python does nothing, running it in the CGI script produces the same results. Another issue is that it's appending everything to the same answer, which would be a big problem to deal with

Comment: GOT IT! I needed to add a print(html) command right at the end of the script, then it works perfectly! Thanks! All I need to do now is work out how to process all the answers being in the same thing (A1)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) - a templating language for python.

In your case your Jinja template should look something like

```
template_string = """
<html>
...
    {% for question, name in questions %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{question}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="{{name}}"/></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
...
</html>
"""
```

Then you load the template string from your code and call the rendering function passing it your data (in this case a list of tuples containing the question and name)

```
question_list = [("Q1", "name1"), ("Q2", "name2"), ...]
template = Template(template_string)
template.render(questions=questions_list)
```

Comment: Jinja looks useful, I'll give it a go